# Is ok to use functions to format columns inside OVER PARTITION BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a column that its maximum length is 8 characters, but usually it has less.
I tried to normalize it, using the `RIGHT` function. It works very well on JOINS, and it doesn't show syntax errors when I use it in `OVER PARTITION` BY function.
I run the query many times but I think I don't have a database to prove my point, but I want to know if it could be a problem in order to get the total number of rows with the same vcAuth.

```
SELECT TOP 1 @iT40Total = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY RIGHT('00000000'+ [vcAuth],8) )
FROM MyTable
WHERE [bProcessed] = 0
```

My desired result is the number of rows with the same AuthCode. It works just with `@iT40Total = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [vcAuth] )` but using it, I don't know if there is another row with more zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem.  You can use almost any scalar expression for the `partition by` and `order by` clauses with a window function.  To be honest, I have never tried using subqueries, but it is hard to imagine a situation where those would be useful.

That said, using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is suspicious.  And your code snippet is better written with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) @iT40Total = COUNT(*) 
FROM MyTable
WHERE [bProcessed] = 0
GROUP BY RIGHT('00000000' + [vcAuth], 8)
```

Comment: My query assigns a lot of variables with many "partitions" of columns, so I use OVER (PARTITION BY ...) instead of GROUP BY to simplify the code. Thank you for your recommendation and quick answer.